# SFDX CLI Stopped working

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli

I've got message saying "Plugin "salesforcedx" v41 or later may only be used in a v6.0.0 or later CLI", however CLI was working perfectly moments ago.

What can I be missing?

```
>sfdx version
sfdx-cli/6.0.14-2af879b (linux-x64) node-v8.6.0

>sfdx plugins --core
salesforcedx 41.6.0 (core)
```

Thanks,

Daniel

Update: I've also restarted computer and still get same issue. This happen during any sfdx call to SFDC

EDIT:
I've already tried updating sfdx. Below output:

```
>sfdx update 
sfdx-cli: Updating CLI... already on latest version: 6.0.14-2af879b 
sfdx-cli: Updating plugins... done
```

Comment: Have you tried `sfdx update`?

Comment: That was first thing I have done. Result: >sfdx update
sfdx-cli: Updating CLI... already on latest version: 6.0.14-2af879b
sfdx-cli: Updating plugins... done

Answer (score 3):

I am sorry, my bad.

The script was running as another user which sfdx was old.

Logging in as different user and running `sfdx update` solved my issue.

Hope this will help anyone else running scripts on Jenkins...